# Convert input sequence of array of hashes in and represent via grape entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-entity

This is a 2 part question

A newbie to activerecord/Rails.
Once I execute the below activerecord query, I get

```
results = A.joins(:b).group(:id, :status).count
```

this result, now I want to present the results using an entity by postprocessing the output from

```
{[1, "action1"]=>2, [1, "action2"]=>2, [1, "action3"]=>1, [2, "action3"]=>2}
```

to

```
[{'id' => 1, 'action1' => 2, 'action2' => 2, 'action3' => 1}, {'id'=>2, 'action3' => 2, 'action1' => 0, 'action2' => 0} ]
```

(In the expected output's second hash, I added `action1 => 0` and `action2 => 0`, because 0 should be default value.)

How to achieve the above output? I am unsure if the output of the query can be presented without postprocessing itself.
So far I tried

```
summaries.map {|k,v| {k[0] => {k[1] => v}}}.reduce {|acc, h| (acc || {}).deep_merge(h)}
```

need to make changes to the above map-reduce code to get expected result.

The expected response should look like the below, hence I am focussing on post processing the output of the query.

```
[
 { 'id' => value
   'action1' => count,
   'action1' => count,
   'action1' => count
 },
 {
  # same structure as above
 }
]
```

I am trying to expose for example, only the id field in rails console but hitting the error

```
class klassEntity < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
end
```

When I tried

```
klassEntity.represent([{'id' => 1, 'action1' => 2, 'action2' => 2, 'action3' => 1}, {'id'=>2, 'action3' => 2, 'action1' => 0, 'action2' => 0} ])
```

this failed with `(Object doesn't support #inspect)`
What am i doing wrong?

### Update

I got this working by constructing a list of arrays from current output of

```
summaries.map {|k,v| {k[0] => {k[1] => v}}}.reduce {|acc, h| (acc || {}).deep_merge(h)}
```

and each array element contains a hash of symbols. This worked in rails console as well.
I am wondering if there is an optimal way to get here.

Answer (score 0):

Find here an option **using just the standard library**.

I'm using `map` but with object ([Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object)) where the object is a [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a block given to get an empty `hash` as value to call [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) on it:

```
summaries = {[1, "action1"]=>2, [1, "action2"]=>2, [1, "action3"]=>1, [2, "action3"]=>2}

summaries.map.with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {}}){|(v, k), h| h[v.first].merge!({v.last => k})}
```

The result:

```
#=> {1=>{"action1"=>2, "action2"=>2, "action3"=>1}, 2=>{"action3"=>2}}
```